# Rails ERROR: While executing (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I try to install rails with command gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc and then error occur.Below is output of error

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Fetching: multi_json-1.7.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.7.8
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.37.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.37
Fetching: atomic-1.1.12.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed atomic-1.1.12
Fetching: thread_safe-0.1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.1.2
Fetching: activesupport-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.0.0
Fetching: builder-3.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.1.4
Fetching: rack-1.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.5.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
no such name (https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-test-0.6.2.gem)
```

What should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: From encountering something similar (with no resolution as yet), I suspect the problem is that the remote-fetcher isn't handling redirects (302 Found/Moved Temporarily) properly.

Comment: When I received a similar error, I ran with `sudo` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your source either isn't responding properly or the gem can't be found at the source.

Try `gem install rack-test`. If that gives you an error try switching the source you're getting the gem from.

First add the source
`gem source -a 'https://production.cf.rubygems.org'`

Then try installing again.

**OR**

You could try installing directly from a different source with
`gem install rack-test --source 'https://production.cf.rubygems.org'`

Once you get that gem to install properly, try installing rails again.